# what is the better way for array indexing ? normal 0,1,2,3 or any specific value like 13,45,7,123

Tags: php

I am making an array in which i don't want to have the default 0,1,2,3 indexing. SO i am giving specific index value for example 45,78,98,123. In terms of performance which array would be better if i have to iterate this array using that index?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a dictionary, with key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes but i don't know which is better way, that is keeping the index value equal to product_ids(example 45,46,78,90,123,...) or normal 0,1,2,3,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [];
$arr[13] = 13;
$arr[45] = 45;
$arr[7] = 7;
$arr[123] = 456;
foreach($arr as $a){
  echo $a.', ';
}
```

It will echo 13, 45, 7, 456.

It depends on situation, For example: You have products: [{id: 45, name: 'snickers'}, {id: 60, name: 'mars'}], and you want to call them like arr[id], so in this situation you can use arr[45]. When you don't need any ids or smth like this, you can use 0,1,2,3

Comment: I know it will work but which is the better, having 0,1,2,3 or any specific number according to our need like 23,45,67,78,...

Comment: It depends on situation, For example: You have products: [{id: 45, name: 'snickers'}, {id: 60, name: 'mars'}], and you want to call them like arr[id], so in this situation you can use arr[45]. When you don't need any ids or smth like this, you can use 0,1,2,3